# canonical representation of three skew lines in $\mathbb{P}^3$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider three skew (non-intersecting) lines $L,M,N$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$.
Each line is given by two equations of the form $\alpha_{i,j}^\top z = 0, \, i=1,2,3, j = 1,2$, where $z=(z_0,z_1,z_2,z_3)$ are the homogeneous coordinates of $\mathbb{P}^3$ and $\alpha_{i,j} \in \mathbb{P}^3$.

What i want is to show that up to projective equivalence the equations for the three lines can be written as (this is possible according to the hint of
exercise 2.12 in Harris, Algebraic Geometry - a first course)

$L: \, z_0=z_1=0 \\
M: \, z_2=z_3 = 0 \\
N: \, z_0=z_3, \, z_1=z_2.$

Since say $L, M$ are non-intersecting, this implies that $\alpha_{i,j}$ for every $i=1,2, j=1,2$ are in general position. So they are projectively equivalent to $(1,0,0,0), (0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,1)$. This gives us 
the description that we want for $L$ and $M$. But how about $N$?

Note here that the most general result that we have is projective equivalence between two sets of 5 points in general position. In the context of the present question, i am concerned about two things:

1) The fact that the lines $L,M,N$ are skew does not imply in general that 
every group of 5 points among the $\alpha_{i,j}$ will be in general position.

2) The $\alpha_{i,j}$ are six!

**Question:** What am i missing here? How can the above two issues be addressed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let usthink in terms of linear algebra. You have $3$ $2$-dimensional subspaces $S$, $T$ and $U$ in $V=k^4$ which intersect pairwise trivially.

Since $S\cap T=0$, we have $V=S\oplus T$. Let $\{u_1,u_2\}$ be a basis of $U$, and suppose that $u_1=s_1+t_1$ and $u_2=s_2+t_2$ with the $s_i$ in $S$ and the $t_i$ in $T$. Since $U\cap S=U\cap T=0$, the four of $s_1$, $s_2$, $t_1$, $t_2$ are non-zero.

- If $s_1$ and $s_2$ are linearly dependent, so that for example $u_2=\alpha u_1$, then $\alpha u_1-u_2=\alpha t_1-t_2\in T\cap U=0$ so that in fact also $t_2=\alpha t_1$, which is absurd because it tells us that $u_1=u_2$.
- If $t_1$ and $t_2$ are linearly dependent, we can do the same.
- If neither of these two cases occur, then $\{s_1,s_2,t_1,t_2\}$ is a basis of $V$ and if $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ are coordinates with respect to it, the equations of our subspaces are
  \begin{align}
  &x_3=x_4=0 && \text{for $S$,} \\
  &x_1=x_2=0 && \text{for $T$ and} \\
  &x_1-x_3=x_2-x_4=0 && \text{for $U$.}
  \end{align}

Comment: I just found it :-) How did I come up with it? I just explored the possibilities.

Comment: Dear Mariano, there seems to be some mix-up in your first bullet. It is perfectly possible for  $s_1$ and $s_2$ to be  dependent without having $u_2=\alpha u_1$. For example take $u_1=s_1+t_1, u_2=2s_1+t_1$.  So your conclusion  " $\{s_1,s_2,t_1,t_2\}$ is a basis of $V$ " seems to me unwarranted.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg, but in that example $U\ni 2u_1-u_2=2(s_1+t_1)-(2s_1+t_1)=t_1\in T$, so that $t_1=0$, from which we see that $u_1=s_1\in S\cap T=0$, which is impossible. SOmething more is indeed needed, though :-) I'll try to fix it later.

Comment: You are right Mariano: my objection was not valid:sorry.  I have upvoted your answer!

Comment: A geometer should post a geometric answer!

Comment: Dear Mariano, if you have another 2-dimensional subspace $U'$ transverse to $S$ and $T$, the way I see that you can send $U$ to $U'$ while letting $S,T$ fixed is by considering $U,U'$ as the graphs of two linear isomorphisms $f,f':S\to T$ and considering the automorphism $Id_S\oplus (f'\circ f^{-1})$ of  $S\oplus T$, which fixes $S$ pointwise and  lets $T$ globally invariant: that automorphism sends $U$ to $U'$  Maybe this is not so far from what you do. Anyway you are right: if I had tried to *see* what I was talking about instead of blindly typing formulas I would have realized my mistake !

Comment: That's the good way to see it, I think.

Comment: In the first item, is there a typo? I think you meant in the first sentence that $s_2=\alpha s_1$  because you are talking about linear dependencies of $s_1$ and $s_2$ and by assumption the $u_1,u_2$ is part of a basis.